# How do I add some javascript validation to the admin interface form's onsubmit?

Tags: plugins, admin, hooks, javascript, actions

I have a plugin that adds meta boxes to the admin interface and I need to do some validation when the user presses the "update" button before the form is submitted.

Is there a WordPress action or hook to add my function to the form's onsubmit? Or do I need to simply do this:

**Pseudo code**

```
var myInput = document.getElementById( "myMetaBoxInput" );

//Get form from input
var form = myInput.form;

//They have something already set
if ( form.onsubmit )
{
    var previousSubmit = form.onsubmit;

    form.onsubmit = function() {
        //do my code....

        //Call their function
        previousSubmit();
    }
} else form.onsubmit = myfunction;
```

The problem with doing the above is that it's possible that wordpress could have some code that happens on the "update" button's "click" action which will set the form's `onsubmit` to another function and clear mine out.

Answer (score 3):

Every post / page / post type is wrapped around a universal form with the ID of `#post`. So if you want to validate a page before submitting it you just need to say something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#post').submit(function(){
        // Validate Stuff
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then you'll want to actually enqueue your javascript - [View Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if ( 'edit.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

As far as your concern that another on submit handler will cancel out yours, from what I've tested it doesn't matter how many submit handlers return true, if 1 is false, the form will not submit.

Answer (score -1):

This code might help you. I didn't try it in the dashboard but I use it in a page-template.

```
 // JavaScript Document
function valide()
    {
        var re_email =/^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/;
        var mail = document.kontakt.mail.value;
        var name = document.kontakt.name.value;
        var checked = true;

        if (name=="")
        {
        alert ("Please enter a name.");
        checked = false;
        }
        if ((re_email.test(mail))==false || mail.length==0)
        {
        alert ("Please enter a correct e-mail address");
        checked = false;
        }
        if(checked)
        {
        document.kontakt.method = "post";
        document.kontakt.action = "http://xxx";
        document.kontakt.submit();
        }
        return checked;
    }
 //WP-template
 <form onSubmit="return valide()" method="post" name="kontakt">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Name *</td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" size="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>E-Mail</td>
            <td><input name="mail" type="text" size="20"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="2"><br />
            <input name="Senden" type="submit" value="Send"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: I know how to do a form.onsubmit. my question is about hooking it into the default WordPress code